# url/user/unique_username VS /user/id/possible_duplicate, what should I choose?

Tags: database-design, unique

Every time I think to build a new site with multiple users registered inside I always ask myself if it's better with unique usernames or duplicated usernames. An example of the latter is the Stack Overflow site (because it works with the unique user id instead of a unique username).

I always choose the former choice, but I hate it because many times you just can't use your favourite username.

What should I choose? Does some good advice exist for helping to decide?

Answer (score 1):

I think using an e-mail address as the user ID for logging in and having a profile which allows the user to pick a non-unique nickname is the best approach.  The e-mail address is harder to forget and very unlikely (impossible really - except for users trying to open multiple accounts) to get you into name collisions.  You also want to have real e-mail addresses as part of your user profiles anyway because you want to be able to reach your members and you'll eventually need to send a password reset e-mail to many/most users anyway.

Having said that, I would use an internal unique ID for the user profile, such as an IDENTITY integer or a GUID.  This is because e-mail address is not immutable.  You want members to be able to change their e-mails without disrupting your foreign keys.  Still, e-mail should be a candidate key in your user/member table.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow allows duplicate names, but not duplicate users. (Not the way you seem to be talking about.) Each Stack Overflow user has a unique id number, including *[yours](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185921/vittorio)* (it's 185921). Each Stack Overflow user also has a "name" that might not be unique.

Stack Overflow lets each user pick their own "name", but Stack Overflow code doesn't use it. Stack Overflow code uses the unique id number.

Comment: Yes, I've wrote about that only in the question title, now I've repeated it in the question body too.